# About accessibility of full linked cards

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm facing about an issue making HTML cards in my web projects as accessible as I can.
I've found and followed this very good article:

[inclusive-components.design/cards/](https://inclusive-components.design/cards/)

And  I've used the javascript technique, showed in this demo:

[cards redundant click](https://heydon.github.io/Inclusive-Components/cards-redundant-click/)

It seems ok, testing the result with keyboard navigation and NVDA Screen Reader.

When I try to submit my project (or even this example) to an online validator, or if I use Firefox accessibility tool, I have alerts regarding the inner contents of the cards:

- online validator: "Elements that behave as buttons but are built using other tags such as span, div, a or others, should include a "role" attribute that equals to "button".
- firefox: "Clickable elements must be focusable and should have interactive semantics"

I think the problem is that javascript makes inner divs clickable, when the tool expects "A" tag or buttons.

Do I need to consider these a real accessibility issue? If yes, can I resolve refining the code or I have to abandon the idea of full linked cards?

According to my tests (I've not tested all screen reader tools, of course) I haven't met a practical problem about.
I think there can be a potential problem of difficult touch on mobile devices if card is very big, and a potential problem about an unexpected behaviour of the card for users that think  the entire card is not clickable.
But if I abandon the idea of a full clickable card, I have the issue of users that expect the entire card is clickable,a pretty standard behaviour...

What do you think? Can I consider this technique accessible-safe?

Thanks

Comment: Easiest solution is to add `role="button"` to any clickable HTML element.

Comment: I can try, but it doesn't create an effect worse than then issue? I have to test behaviour with screen reader

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @zer00ne adding `role="button"` to elements that aren't semantically buttons is actively harmful for accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem here, since the action of the clickable full card link can be triggered by the regular H2 title link.
As long as there is one accessible way to trigger the action, it shouldn't be a problem. The article looks of good advice, and even quite smart in fact.

Making the whole card content focusable will cause the issue explained at the beginning of the article: a lot of content for a single focusable element making it unclear, focusable/clickable element one inside another, and so on.
So you certainly shouldn't do what the tool is saying in this particular case.

Remember that automated accessibility tools are just tools which can have false positives and false negatives. They are far from perfect beyond very basic things. In this case, it can't detect that a click anywhere on the card is the same as clicking on the title link directly.

Messages that tools raise should make you ask yourself if what you have done is really legitimate. They can remind you about things you may have missed, or things that can look odd.
But you should never blindly apply what they say without thinking about it, just to make the message disappear.